# How to convert 'HH:MM' to a particular GMT time on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, gmt

Suppose that you have a variable that stores the following time zone format as string type:

```
timezone = '(GMT -5:00)'
```

Now you have the following times, which were set in `GMT -4:00` time and as string types:

```
time1 = '4:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
time2 = '9:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
```

How can be used the variable `timezone` to change the `time1` and `time2` values to its corresponding local times? that is:

```
time1 = '3:00' #am  (GMT -5:00)
time2 = '8:00' #am  (GMT -5:00)
```

Comment: what did you try? besides, I think "timezone" is misleading here - you just need `timedelta`. neither is GMT a time zone (it's mean solar time in Greenwich), nor does it make sense to assign a time zone without providing date information (UTC offsets of different time zones change depending on the date).

Comment: I just learnt that by adding `from datetime import datetime`,
`from time import gmtime, strftime` I can get the actual GMT offset of User by using `print("Your Time Zone is GMT", strftime("%z", gmtime()))`, I need this information this way because `time1 = '4:00'` `time2 = '9:00'` must be overwritten depending on which `GMT offset` the user has.

Comment: still, a UTC offset is not a time zone. also, if you use the user's local time, that includes a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it ain't that great but it's honest work:

```
import datetime

timezone = '(GMT -5:00)'
timezone = timezone.replace("(", "").replace("GMT ", "").replace(":","").replace(")", "")
gmt_hours = int(timezone[:2])

gmt_less_4_hours = -4

time_difference = abs(gmt_hours - gmt_less_4_hours)

time1 = "04:00" #am  (GMT -4:00)
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1, "%H:%M")
time1 -= datetime.timedelta(hours=time_difference)
time1 = time1.strftime('%H:%M')
print(time1)

time2 = '9:00' #am  (GMT -4:00)
time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2, "%H:%M")
time2 -= datetime.timedelta(hours=time_difference)
time2 = time2.strftime('%H:%M')
print(time2)
```

**Output:**

> 03:00
>
> 08:00